# Average of a selection of values after randomly removing values.

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Say I have a list of 10 values;

$ [1,2,3,4,5,8,10,15,20,30]$.

The average of these values is $9.8$. Say I randomly remove 1 of these values. What would the average be? 
What if I had 18 values? What if i removed 6 values? Is there a formula for this kind of thing?

Comment: If you don't know which value was removed, of course you cannot tell what the new average is. So are you looking for some expected value for the average?

Comment: Since the original list of $10$ items sums to $98$, if you remove number $i$ the average $\frac {98-i}9$.  Is that what you are asking?

Comment: If you have a list of length $n$ with average $\mu$, and you randomly delete $k$ of these values (so that each of the $\binom{n}k$ selections is equally likely), then the expected value of the average of what remains is $\mu$.

Comment: @MikeEarnest can you prove this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$ be a list of numbers, and let $S$ be a random subset of $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ of size $k$. The average of the members of $S$ can be written as
$$
\frac1k\sum_{k=1}^nx_i\cdot {\bf 1}(i\in S)
$$
By linearity of expectation, the expected value of this is
$$
\frac1k\sum_{k=1}^nx_i\cdot \mathbb P(i\in S)
$$
What is the probability a particular element of $i$ is included in $S$? In order to choose a subset containing $i$, you need to choose $k-1$ elements from the $n-1$ other elements, so 
$$
\frac1k\sum_{k=1}^nx_i\cdot \mathbb P(i\in S)=\frac1k\sum_{k=1}^n x_i\cdot \frac{\binom{n-1}{k-1}}{\binom{n}k}=\frac1k\sum_{k=1}^n x_i\cdot \frac{k}{n}=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n x_i
$$
Therefore, the average of the re-sample average is the original average.